# Start a neuronal network project

Tags: frameworks, machine-learning, programming-languages, neural-network

after a long term of reading the theory behind neural networks I finally want to stark to do my own project in object recognition.
However I struggle to find a practical entry point. I want to use either C#,C++ or C however all new tutorials seem to involve newer languages such as python.

For starting I would especially like to reprogram  the theory concepts of Yann LeCuns publications about object recognition.

Which programming language is recommended to use? And much more important: Which framework do I use? There seem to be docents of frameworks (AForge,  Apache Mahout, OpenCV) and my theoretical knowledge seems to be too impractical to differentiate the usage of these.

I want to program a simple independent  neural network application which should be easy trainable plus I don't want to reprogram classes such as neuron or layer in order to focus on the architecture for the beginning.

Thanks and sorry for the simple probably often ask question, however I just couldn't find anything matching.

Greetings
Nex

Answer (score 1):

disclosure: i'm not an expert.

depends on what exactly you want to do.

- if you want to build something from scratch, probably the easiest language to start prototyping is matlab/octave because it's high level and offers pretty fast matrix manipulations, nice math support (like numeric derivatives) and robust plotting to quickly verify your models. when you have your prototype, you can port to to c/c++ to make it faster, more space efficient, portable etc.
- if you want to just use exiting tools/techniques and just play with parameters (preprocessing, feature selection etc) to find the best model for you, i would recommend start from R and caret package or python (don't remember the package name)
- if you want to use NN in cluster on big data then i would try using existing frameworks like openCV (not sure if mahout provides NN)

Comment: Google just released their tensorflow framework. Its perfect. I recommand it to use for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Google just released their tensorflow framework. 
Its perfect to start with and offers even for high skilled NN-architectures a lot of feautes. I highly recommend it for everyone.